# Netbeans грузит проц при вытягивании с github

Tags: github, netbeans

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите почему может netbeans грузить проц при вытягивании с github, и это может дляться от 10 до 20мин, это совсем не реально((( java я обнавлял

Comment: Что у вас за проекты? NetBeans конешно не простой парень, но чтобы так...

Comment: идет скрытое сканирование новых исходников? )

Comment: а если с консоли потянуть проект? Хотя проекты разные бывают. Может там ядро линукса тянется.

Comment: да обыкновенный проект, некоторые файлы CMS затягиваю, нечего осбенного, у меня стоит Windows 7 64бит и NetBeans 7,3,1 тоже 64бит, проект выгружается на WD Green а система стоит на SSD, я думал может ему мощи WD не хватает(((

Comment: "идет скрытое сканирование новых исходников? )"

да одновременно еще идет сканирование(( http://prntscr.com/1qsvs7

Comment: заметил что вытягивание происходит на самом деле быстро если читать в окне консоли
==[IDE]== 12.09.2013 12:36:38 Выполняется вытягивание...
-//-//-//-
Обновления отсутствуют
-//-//-//-

а вот внизу впанельке http://prntscr.com/1qsvs7 так и висит по пол часа!!! и все четыри ядра на проце 90%